# Designing a notation for the "even part" or "even floor" of a number

Tags: math-mode, symbols, brackets

The largest even number less than or equal to either 6 or 7 is 6.  Whether 6 should be called the “even part” of those numbers or the “even floor” of those numbers or something else was the topic of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649867/standard-name-or-notation-for-the-even-part-of-an-integer). Here my questions are (1) What would be a felicitous notation for this, just as compact and efficient as `\lfloor 7 \rfloor`, and (2) How would one code that notation in LaTeX?

Comment: This really seems off topic to me as it is. If you come up with the notation and then would like to know how to produce it in LaTeX (especially if you come with an MWE and even an attempt of your own) then things will be very different :)

Comment: I agree with Au101 that the question about what the notation ought to be is off-topic here and is probably better discussed at Maths.SE (if they allow it). The implementation of any notation you come up with though will definitely be on-topic here. (I have not yet voted to close this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any notation for this, but you can easily create it.  Since there is already a 'floor' symbol, then one shouldn't move too far away from it.  I think simply adding a subscript should be clear enough, and this follows the general idea used by logarithms.  You'll have to make sure to define it when you use it.

You could just use `\lfloor 7 \lfloor_{2}`; but while we're at it, I created a `\floor` function that takes an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\floor{
  \@ifnextchar[\floor@opt{\floor@noopt}}
\def\floor@opt[#1]#2{
  \floor@noopt{#2}_{#1}
}
\def\floor@noopt#1{
  \lfloor #1 \rfloor
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \floor{7.2} &= 7 &
  \floor[2]{7.2} &= 6 &
  \floor[4]{7.2} &= 4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: output]